# Railstutorial 6.3.5 Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password, password_confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

Hartl's Rails book 6.3.5. Trying to insert someone into the db, this error pops up.

I have done some research and I have this in the User model:

```
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
has_secure_password
```

I think there is a problem with my model. Because this is what the user looks like:

```
 #<User id: nil, name: "Da", email: "da@yahoo.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil>
```

so basically when i try this:

```
User.create(name: "Da", email: "da@yahoo.com", password: "da", password_confirmation: "da")
```

I get the Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password, password_confirmation error.

What to do?

Comment: When you say "this is what the user looks like", where do you see that if you got an error on creation?  Your `attr_accessible` statement looks fine and the fields in the `User` instance look correct as well.  Can you share your full error output and perhaps your full `User` class definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I solved it already. I just restarted the Ruby console, which led to another error (the entries I insert kept getting rolled back). Well I was inserting invalid names so I corrected it. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ,

```
  attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
```

to your model

Comment: Thanks but I solved it already. I just restarted the Ruby console, which led to another error (the entries I insert kept getting rolled back). Well I was inserting invalid names so I corrected it. Everything works now.